# How to replace 0 with "NA" and all other values to 0 in Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a dataframe

```
dict = {'col1': [1,2,np.nan,4],
        'col2': [1,2,0,4],
        'col3': [0,2,3,4],
        'col4': [1,2,0,np.nan],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

```
>> df

col1 col2 col3  col4
0   1.0 1   0   1.0
1   2.0 2   2   2.0
2   NaN 0   3   0.0
3   4.0 4   4   NaN
```

I want to replace all 0 with a string "NA" and all the rest with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and assign back ouput:

```
df[:] = np.where(df.eq(0), 'NA', 0)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0    0    0   NA    0
1    0    0    0    0
2    0   NA    0   NA
3    0    0    0    0
```

Or use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with convert `False`s of mask to `0`:

```
m = df.eq(0)
df1 = m.astype(int).mask(m, 'NA')
print (df1)
    col1 col2 col3 col4
0     0    0   NA    0
1     0    0    0    0
2     0   NA    0   NA
3     0    0    0    0
```

EDIT: If need processing all columns without `col1` column:

```
cols = df.columns.drop('col1')
df[cols] = np.where(df[cols].eq(0), 'NA', 0)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1.0    0   NA    0
1   2.0    0    0    0
2   NaN    0   NA
3   4.0    0    0    0
```

If need processig all columns without first column:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(0), 'NA', 0)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1.0    0   NA    0
1   2.0    0    0    0
2   NaN   NA    0   NA
3   4.0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Can you tell me what to do if I do not want to replace values of col1 and do this for the rest of the columns?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df==0, 'NA', 0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    0    0   NA    0
1    0    0    0    0
2    0   NA    0   NA
3    0    0    0    0
```

Variant if you want to keep some columns intact:

```
keep = ['col1']

out = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df==0, 'NA', 0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

out[keep] = df[keep]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1.0    0   NA    0
1   2.0    0    0    0
2   NaN   NA    0   NA
3   4.0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. Can you tell me what to do if I do not want to replace values of col1 and do this for the rest of the columns?

Comment: @Ash it depends, do you want a new object or in place modification?